# Laravel Guzzle GET request

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

```
    $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.tvmaze.com/']);

    $res = $client->request('GET', '/schedule?country=US&date=2014-12-01');

    return $res;
```

returns this error:

```
"Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory' not found"
```

I've tried including "symfony/psr-http-message-bridge": "0.2", in my composer.json file

Answer (score 11):

You need to get the body of the answer:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.tvmaze.com/']);

$res = $client->request('GET', '/schedule?country=US&date=2014-12-01');

return $res->getBody();
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

That's a bit old question. However, since the answers couldn't resolve it for me, here is a last thing to try when using Guzzle Http.

According to Laravel Documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests#psr7-requests :

> The PSR-7 standard specifies interfaces for HTTP messages, including requests and responses. If you would like to obtain an instance of a PSR-7 request instead of a Laravel request, you will first need to install a few libraries. Laravel uses the Symfony HTTP Message Bridge component to convert typical Laravel requests and responses into PSR-7 compatible implementations:

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require zendframework/zend-diactoros
```

This solved my problem.

**EDIT-------**

As suggested in comments, the package `zendframework/zend-diactoros` is abandoned. Then it's better to use an alternate.

Suggested by [Symfony PSR7 Bridge](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/psr7.html):

```
composer require nyholm/psr7
```

Or [Laminas Diactoros Github Package](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-diactoros):

```
composer require laminas/laminas-diactoros
```

Comment: For those working with `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5"`, it appears that : Package `zendframework/zend-diactoros` is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use `laminas/laminas-diactoros` instead.

Comment: You can also use `composer require nyholm/psr7` instead of `zendframework/zend-diactoros` as it is suggested by Symfony. It works for me!

Comment: fresh install of laravel 8 and problem strill exists. "psr-http-message-bridge" and "nyholm/psr7" installed. composer dumpautoload called. but still not working " Class "Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory" not found "

Answer (score 5):

You need to install the following additional symfony components with composer.

```
composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
composer require nyholm/psr7
```

[https://symfony.com/doc/..](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/psr7.html)

Answer (score 2):

Remove guzzle package first : `composer remove guzzlehttp/guzzle`

then do:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

finally re install it:

`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Also make sure you are using guzzle namespace:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are instantiating a Client but seems like you weren't explicit with the class being instantiated. Try this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://api.tvmaze.com/']);

$res = $client->request('GET', '/schedule?country=US&date=2014-12-01');

return $res;
```