# What causes the Class not found error in this Laravel 8 API?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on a **Laravel 8** API. I use **Auth0** for user registration and login. I need the user's id returned by Auth0 to use in my own application.

For this purpose I have the code, I have installed Guzzle with `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle:^7.0`.

In *routes\api.php* I have the following:

```
// Public routes
Route::get('/authorization', [AuthController::class, 'authorization']);

// Protected routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['jwt']], function () {
  Route::get('/user', [UserController::class, 'getUserId']);
});
```

In the **AuthController** I have:

```
class AuthController extends Controller{
  
    protected $appDomain;
    protected $appClientId;
    protected $appClientSecret;
    protected $appAudience;
    
    protected function authorization(){

        $this->appDomain = 'https://' . config('laravel-auth0.domain');
        $this->appClientId = config('laravel-auth0.client_id');
        $this->appClientSecret = config('laravel-auth0.client_secret');
        $this->appAudience = config('laravel-auth0.api_identifier');

        $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;

        try {
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $response = $client->request('POST', $this->appDomain . '/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                        "client_id" =>        $this->appClientId,
                        "client_secret" =>    $this->appClientSecret,
                        "audience" =>         $this->appAudience,
                        "grant_type" =>       "client_credentials"
                ]
            ]);
        
            $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
        }
        catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
            $response = $e->getResponse();
        }

        return $response;

    }
}
```

In the **UserController** I have:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends AuthController {

    // More code

    public function getUserId(){

    $access_token = parent::authorization()->access_token;

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
        try {
              $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['headers' => [
                 'authorization' => 'Bearer' . $access_token,
                 'content-type' => 'application/json'
               ]]);
                
              $response = $client->request('GET', $this->appDomain . '/userinfo');

              $response = json_decode($response->getBody());
        }
        catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
                $response = $e->getResponse();
        }

        return  $response;
    }

    // More code
}
```

#### The problem

Using `dd($access_token)` does return a **valid token**. Yet, I get this error in Postman:

```
Error: Class 'Symfony\Bridge\PsrHttpMessage\Factory\HttpFoundationFactory' not found in \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php
```

#### Question

Where is my mistake?

#### UPDATE

As adviced in the comments, I run `composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge` and `composer require nyholm/psr7`.

But `getUserId` now returns `Unauthorized`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Guzzle GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331903/laravel-guzzle-get-request)

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I am just curious, why aren't you using Laravel Http Client https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client ?

Comment: @AbdullahAlFarooq I don't know how to. Also, I would like to know what causes that error and I can not figure it out.

Comment: Why class AuthController extends Controllern ? not Contoller which is base class in laravel. Is Controllern valid name of your base class ?

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar It does not. It was just a typo, in the question, **not** the app.

Comment: Nothing looks wrong from code side then, Could you try these two command in your terminal where your project resides,
`1) composer require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge
 2) composer require nyholm/psr7
`

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar `No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets]`. For both commands. But `getUserId`  now returns `Unauthorized`.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I think you are getting some exceptions in your code. Could you please try `catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) { $response = $e->getResponse(); dd($e) }`. And add the output of dd($e) from catch block to question. So that I can see what is exact error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241715/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-onkar-manvelikar).